# Moving File in IsolatedStorage Not Permitted Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a background downloads of a file, this is the code:

```
LiveOperationResult downloadResult = await client.BackgroundDownloadAsync(id, new Uri("/shared/transfers/MyDB.sdf", UriKind.Relative));
```

then i must copy downloaded file from shared/transfer folder to root folder of isolatedStorage with the following code.

```
  using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                    {
                        storage.MoveFile("/shared/transfers/MyDB.sdf", "MyDB.sdf");                            
                    }
```

When execute the instruction storage.MoveFile(...) i have an IsolatedStorage Operation Not Permitted exception. I don't understand the reason. thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably BackgroundTransfers still use the file, thus you cannot delete it. Try to [remove transfer request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286419(v=vs.105).aspx) when it is finished

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the target file doesn't exist before moving the file.

```
if (storage.FileExists("MyDB.sdf"))
{
    storage.DeleteFile("MyDB.sdf");
}
storage.MoveFile("/shared/transfers/MyDB.sdf", "MyDB.sdf");
```

Also ensure that the source file stream is not open anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answering.

But for anyone who faces the same issue try this

Instead of moving to root folder, move it to some other folder inside roor. I faced this same problem on windows phone 8 when i was creating files on root folder of Isolated Storage. And for some reason my device was not showing any issues. when my app went live then i got to know about it. It was very hard to find.